# How to return a HTMLDIvElement from a react class already created?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I need to return an HTMLElement from a function,

```
init = function(params) {
var htmlDIV = document.createElement('div');
this.modifyDIV.innerHTML='hello';
return htmlDIV;
}
```

this implementation works fine since innerHTML just has a plain text. But I wanted to include another react class/component instead of plain "hello". Could anyone give some clue on this?

Comment: EditedCellNotifierComponent_backup.prototype.getGui = function() {

  return <div> <SvgIcon id="SVGIconID" iconColor="#249" icon="ic_health" /> </div>;

};     This is the method which I tried throwing the error like this, cellComp.js:595 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at CellComp../node_modules/ag-

Comment: tried like  getGui = function() {

  var temp= document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML=<SvgIcon id="SVGIconID" iconColor="#249" icon="ic_health" />;
  return temp;

};

Comment: it just displays  [ Object Object] but no error though

Comment: for reference SvgIcon used here is my own react class. takes those props as mentioned..

Comment: getGui(): HTMLElement; is the method signature..

Comment: Basically, i need to get HTMLElement from a react class and return it.

Answer (score 0):

```
init = function(params) {
return <div>
        <MyReactComponent />
   </div>;
}
```

You can directly return the `react component` inside a div.

Comment: cellComp.js:595 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at CellComp../node_modules/ag-

Comment: Basically, i need to get HTMLElement object from a react class and return it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const init  = (params) => (<div> <HtmlComponent/> </div>);

const HtmlComponent = (props) = > {
return(
  <div>
    //do whatever you want to do
  </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: cellComp.js:595 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at CellComp../node_modules/ag-   
 Added like this method was getGUI 
 sinated of init EditedCellNotifierComponent_backup.prototype.getGui = function() {

  return <div> <SvgIcon id="SVGIconID" iconColor="#249" icon="ic_health" /> </div>;

};

Comment: Basically, i need to get HTMLElement object from a react class and return it.